# VB Code to Export Multiple pages into a single PDF File

Tags: excel, vba

This small VB Chunk iterates from roll no 1 to last (collecting data from sheet1 and getting results.
but unfortunately, it exports only the last result instead of all the iterated results.
All I want is just to export all the iterated results into a single pdf file on the said path.

```
Sub printPDF()
For n = 5 To 15 
RollNo = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, "A")
StudentName = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, "C")
Sheets("Results").Cells(13, "M") = RollNo
Next n
Sheet7.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "C:\result\" & RollNo & "-" & StudentName & ".pdf", , , False, , , False
End Sub
```

I think the code is not saving the iterated results into its queue because it works fine but prints just last result,

Comment: The line `Sheet7.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "C:\result\" & RollNo & "-" & StudentName & ".pdf", , , False, , , False` is outside your `For` statement, move it above the `Next n` so it is part of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you export 10 sheets, (one for each iteration):

```
Sub printPDF()
For n = 5 To 15 
RollNo = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, "A")
StudentName = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, "C")
Sheets("Results").Cells(13, "M") = RollNo
Sheet7.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "C:\result\" & RollNo & "-" & StudentName & ".pdf", , , False, , , False
Next n
End Sub
```

If you want to export one sheet with all the iterated values concatenated into the exported file name:

```
Sub printPDF()
RollNo = ""
StudentName = ""
For n = 5 To 15 
RollNo = RollNo & "-" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, "A")
StudentName = StudentName & "-" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, "C")
Sheets("Results").Cells(13, "M") = RollNo
Next n
Sheet7.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "C:\result\" & RollNo & "-" & StudentName & ".pdf", , , False, , , False
End Sub
```

If that's not what you're trying to do, please give more details.